# find 2nd highest salary in sql

Tags: sql-server

There are two tables, `Employee` and `Salary`.

- The `Employee` table has columns `EmpID`, `EmpName` of employees
- The `Salary` table contains `EmpID`, `Payment`

I want to retrieve employee details whose payment is 2nd highest.

Please give me solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a "please give code" site

Comment: Hello Pankaj, Kindly see the solution i have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT 
    MIN(s.Payment), e.EmpName, e.EmpID 
FROM 
    dbo.Employee e 
INNER JOIN
    Salary s ON e.EmpID = s.EmpID
WHERE 
    e.EmpID IN (SELECT TOP 2 EmpID FROM dbo.Salary ORDER BY Payment DESC)
```

Comment: thanks sir its working

Comment: This will return the **highest** and the second-highest value ....

Comment: This will return the second highest values only.

Comment: You are welcome always.

Comment: Yes, this return both highest and 2nd highest salary